# Error: A partials dir must be a string or config object in handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I am sending templated email using `nodemailer` with `nodemailer-express-handlebars`, but whenever I am trying to send a mail, I am getting the

`Error: A partials dir must be a string or config object.`

I don't know what is the problem.

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();

const user_name     = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
const refresh_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const client_id     = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const email_to = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com';

let transporter = nodemailer
    .createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            clientId: client_id,
            clientSecret: client_secret
        },
        tls:{
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
transporter.use('compile', hbs({
    viewPath: 'views/email',
    extName: '.hbs'
}));
transporter.on('token', token => {
    console.log('A new access token was generated');
    console.log('User: %s', token.user);
    console.log('Access Token: %s', token.accessToken);
    console.log('Expires: %s', new Date(token.expires));
});
let mailOptions = {
    from    : user_name,
    to      : email_to,
    subject : 'Hello ✔',
    text    : 'Hello world ?',
    template: 'emailt',
    context: {},
    auth : {
        user         : user_name,
        refreshToken : refresh_token,
        expires      : 1494388182480
    }
};

// send mail with defined transport object


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then( r => {
        res.send(r);
    }).catch(e =>{
        res.send(e);
    });
});
app.listen(3000 ,()=>{
    console.log('port: 3000');
});
```

My directory looks like this `views>email>emailt.hbs`

Comment: Did you set a `partialsDir` anywhere? Where are your `viewEngine` params?

Comment: Yeah - I got this same error today, after running 'npm update' yesterday

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a recent change to express-handlebars caused this issue, someone posted a fix here https://github.com/yads/nodemailer-express-handlebars/issues/22

Or

I guess you could just go back to a version that doesn't have this issue, at least until it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get my code working, posting in case it helps out. I had to add the `partialsDir` to my `handlebarOptions` where I didn't have the field before:

```js
const handlebarOptions = {
  viewEngine: {
    extName: '.hbs',
    partialsDir: 'src/path',
    layoutsDir: 'src/path',
    defaultLayout: 'email.hbs',
  },
  viewPath: 'src/path',
  extName: '.hbs',
};

transporter.use('compile', hbs(handlebarOptions));
```

Hope this helps.